# Insert data with associative array using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Before you duplicate your question, I read all answers that it's has a relation with my question. I'm trying to  insert data with associative array for example

```
<?php 
$data = array(
   'fname'=>'joe',
   'lname'=>'sina'
);
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
                 
}
?>
```

I want to display data like this

```
/*insert into tblname($key)values($value);
 finally the query will appear correctly format */
insert into tblname('fname','lname') values('joe','sina');
```

Comment: Use an `'\`' . implode('\`', array_keys($data)) . '\`';` to create the column list

Comment: Use a `count($data)` to get the number of placeholders that you need for binding, an then build the binders using `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($data), '?'));`

Comment: And pass the array to the `execute()` call for your bind and execute in a single step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreach` here. If you just prepare and bind the query, you can pass `$data` to the `execute()` and get the keys by `implode()` on the keys.

```
$data = array(
         'fname'=>'joe',
         'lname'=>'sina'
);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tblname (".implode(', ', array_keys($data)).") VALUES (:".implode(', :', array_keys($data)).")");
$stmt->execute($data);
```

The keys in the array must match the placeholders in the query (the ones with a colon in front of it). You also had a syntax error in the query, as columns cannot be quoted by singlequotes.

Comment: just to learn, can you kindly explain why there is no need of `array_values`? Thank you. I mean if you kindly can teach what happen in the `$pdo->prepare` line of code, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, @Robert. Are you wondering why its using `array_keys()` without `array_values()`? That's because we need to create the columns based on the keys, but we also need to keep the key/value pair when passing it into `execute()`. We only care about the values in `execute()`, but we can not remove the keys.

Comment: Ok, now I got the point, than you for the explanation.